# Reading user input strings that contain '+' - Python

Tags: python, string

I'm writing a small program to take a simple mathematical expression as input and evaluate it (haven't gotten that far as of yet).

The expressions only consist of +, -, /, and *. The problem I seem to be having is that whenever I input a string such as "1 + 2 + 3 + 4", I get an error:

```
1 2 3 4
invalid syntax
```

From what I can tell, the '+' is being interpreted as concatenation.

Is there a proper way to read a user input string that contains the + symbol?

Python 2.7

What I have:

```
expr = raw_input()
print expr
```

Given the input "1+2+3+4", python seems to automatically concatenate this to "1 2 3 4". I want the string to be verbatim, not concatenated

Comment: Please show your code so we can help with your problem. Also indicate what version of Python you are using.

Comment: Added python version and clarified a bit